# not all arguments converted during string formatting error with modulus

Tags: python

i was making a clock in python and tested it, it wasent working. In the shell, it says ''not all arguments converted during string formatting'' i dont really know what to do to repare this cause i just know that a string is a series of numbers i think. Any ways, i was trying to make the turtle orientate to the good spot for the hours hour pointer. So, i think its with the modulus. Here is the code for now (dont look at the unfinished part, its not finished)

```
import turtle
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from turtle import *

def DRAW ():
    turtle.clear()
    DRAW2()
    DRAW4()
    turtle.pensize(4)
    DRAW1()
    DRAW5()
    DRAW3()
    DRAW7()



def DRAW1 ():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(0)
    turtle.sety(-50)
    turtle.pendown()
    now = datetime.now()
    current_minute = now.strftime('%M')
    current_sec = now.strftime('%S')
    current_hour = now.strftime('%H')
    print((((current_hour % 12) * 30) + (current_minute / 2)))    <---

def DRAW2 ():
    hello = 2

def DRAW3 ():
    hello = 8

def DRAW4 ():
    hello = 3

def DRAW5 ():
    hello = 89
    
def DRAW7 ():
    je = 3
    
DRAW()
```

Comment: `current_hour` and `current_minute` are strings, not numbers, you can't perform arithmetic on them.

Answer (score 1):

`current_hour` is a string, not an integer, because `strftime()` is for formatting dates and times as strings. So `%` is the string formatting operator, not modulus.

There's no need to use `strftime`. The `datetime` object has attributes with the components. So use

```
current_hour = now.hour
current_minute = now.minute
current_sec = now.second
```